# Linq to SQL Contains Method Throwing Unsupported Overload Exception

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a List and each Filter object has a property called "Id". I want to fetch all the records from my database using Linq to SQL that contains those ids. The List is not part of the database it is just an independent list.

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to help. Please add some code including the code throwing the Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not very clear question. however this is what, i suppose, u r trying to do

```
from c in datacontext.TableName where
IndependentList.Contains(c=>c.id)
select c
```